# Output the decimal versions of unknown input

Tags: c, hex, decimal, octal

I'm trying to write a short script to take in 6 inputs that will be in decimal, hex or octal and output their decimal versions. For example, if I input 1, 1 should be output. Input 010, should get 8, input 0x20, should get 32. Do I have to test each value to see if scanf reads it as its type or can I cast them after scanf reads them all as is? Also do I need functions to convert the octal and hex values to decimal or can I cast them? I'm very new to C and don't understand it well yet, but here's what I have so far (it outputs -200 as 32765 for whatever reason):

```
    int num[6];
    printf("Enter six integers:\n");

    int i = 0;
    int j;
    while (i < 6){
            if(scanf("0x%x", &j) == 1){
                    scanf("0x%x", &num[i]);
                    //hexToDec(num[i]);
            } else if (scanf("0%o", &j) == 1){
                    scanf("0%o", &num[i]);
                    //octalToDec(num[i]);
            } else {
                     scanf("%i", &num[i]);
            }
            i+=1;
    }

    for(int p = 0; p < 6; p+=1){
            printf("%i\n", num[p]);
    }
```

Comment: Use `"%i"` only.

Comment: Using `%i` is enough to do the conversions for you.

Comment: https://ideone.com/lcVcr4

Comment: Well, I made that much harder than it needed to be, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Answer for future reference: simply scanning in with "%i" does the conversions automatically. Revised code below:

```
int main(){

    int num[6];
    printf("Enter six integers:\n");

    int i = 0;
    while (i < 6){
            scanf("%i", &num[i]);
            i+=1;
    }

    for(int p = 0; p < 6; p+=1){
            printf("%i\n", num[p]);
    }
```

}

Comment: OP's code made some attempt to properly check the return value of `scanf()`.  I recommend this answer  also check the `scanf()` return value rather than omit.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `scanf("0x%x", &j)` to test the input and then use `scanf("0x%x", &num[i])` to put the value in `num[i]`. `scanf` *consumes* the characters it accepts, so they are no longer in the input stream. When you do the second `scanf`, the characters are gone.

Instead, just attempt to scan the desired thing. If it works, you are done. If it does not work, go on to an `else`:

```
if (scanf("0x%x", &num[i]) == 1)
    ; // Worked, nothing to do.
else if (scanf("0%o", &num[i]) == 1)
    ;
else if (scanf("%i", &num[i]) == 1)
    ;
else
{
    // Nothing worked, should put error-handling code here.
}
```

That is actually not great code for real applications, because `scanf` will consumes some of the input even if it ultimately fails. For example, with `scanf("0x%x", &num[i])`, if the input contains “0x” but then contains a non-hexadecimal character, `scanf` will consume the “0x” but leave the next character. However, it suffices for a learning exercise.

Once you have values in the `num` array, they are just `int` values. They are mathematical values, not numerals that are in octal, decimal, or hexadecimal. You can print them with `%o` for octal, or `%d` or `%i` for decimal. The original numeral is irrelevant. When printing, the mathematical value will be used to format a string in the requested base.

You should not use `%x` for printing an `int`, as `%x` is for `unsigned int`. However, you could convert an `int` to `unsigned int` and then print it with `%x`.

Note that you should not scan to `int` objects with `%x`. `%x` is for scanning to `unsigned int` objects. You can actually scan hexadecimal, octal, and decimal using:

```
if (scanf("%i", &num[i]) == 1)
    ;
else
    …
```

The `%i` specification will recognize hexadecimal numerals beginning with “0x”, octal numerals beginning with “0”, and decimal numerals.

If you did not want to use `%i` for all three, because you want direct control for some reason, you will need to write more code. Standard C does not provide a direct way to scan only a hexadecimal numeral to an `int`. You would need to get the characters from the input and calculate the value from them or scan to an `unsigned int` and then convert the result to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `strtol` with a base of `0` to do auto-detection of the integral value's base according to the input strings format (cf, for example, [strtol](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) documentation at cppreference.com):

> **long  strtol( const char *str, char **str_end, int base )**
>
> Interprets an integer value in a byte string pointed to by str. ...
>   The valid integer value consists of the following parts:
>
> - (optional) plus or minus sign
> - (optional) prefix (0) indicating octal base (applies only when the base is 8 or ​0​)
> - (optional) prefix (0x or 0X) indicating hexadecimal base (applies only when the base is 16 or ​0​)
>
> If the value of base is ​0​, the numeric base is auto-detected.

So a call like `long val = strtol("0x10",NULL,0);` will yield a decimal value of 16.

Note that you can also use [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) in conjunction with format specifier `%i`, since this is defined to behave just as a call to `strtol`:

> **​int scanf( const char          *format, ... )**
>
> **%i** matches an integer. The format of the number is the same as expected by strtol() with the value ​0​ for the base argument (base is
>   determined by the first characters parsed)

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is use *only*

```
if(scanf("%i", &j) == 1){
  ...
}
```

---

> what I have so far (it outputs -200 as 32765 for whatever reason):

Yet error handing of `scanf()` is troublesome.  Far better to read the *line* of user input with `fgets()` and then parse the line - perhaps with `strtol()`.